# Stationary Excess Expectation Proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $X$ be a positive random variable whose moments are all finite. Define the *stationary excess* $X_{e}$ to be the random variable with distribution

$$P\{X_{e}\leq t\} = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}X} \int_0^t P\{X>s\} ds$$

Show that if $f$ is a differentiable function where $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[f'(X_e)]$ are well defined, then

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X)-f(0)]}{\mathbb{E}X} = \mathbb{E}[f'(X_e)]$$.

**My attempt:** By the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}[f(X)-f(0)] &=& \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^X f'(\xi)  \ d\xi \right] \\
&=& \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{X\geq \xi} f'(\xi)  \ d\xi \right] \\
&=& \int_0^\infty P\{X\geq \xi\} f'(\xi)  \ d\xi
\end{eqnarray}$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you write down the expectation of$f'(X_e)$? It should look very familiar.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{E}[f'(X_e)] = \int_0^\infty f'(\xi) P\{\ X_e = \xi \} \ d\xi$? Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of expectation we have: $$E(g(X))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)h(x)dx, $$
where $h(x)$ is a pdf of $X$.

Now $$E(f'(X_e))=\int_0^\infty f'(x)h_e(x)dx $$
and $h_e(x)$ pdf of $X_e$. What does $h_e(x)$ equal?

Let calculate it directly from the $h_e(t)=(P\{X_e\leq t\})_t'=(\frac{1}{E(X)}\int_0^tP\{X> s\}ds)_t'=\frac{1}{E(X)}P\{X>t\}.$

Now just plug-in this $h_e(x)$ into the $E(f'(X_e))$ formula and get the result you need:

$$E(f'(X_e))=\frac{1}{E(X)}\int_0^\infty f'(x)P\{X>x\}dx, $$
does it look familiar now?

Comment: When you take the derivative of the CDF, don't you get $P\{X>t\}-P\{X>0\}$ instead of just $P\{X>t\}$?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{f_1(t)}^{f_2(t)}g(x)dx=g(f_2(t))f'_2(t)-g(f_1(t))f'_1(t),$$ where in our case: $f_2(t)=t, f'_2(t)=1, f_1(t)=0, f'_1(t)=0.$

Comment: @rpa: No.  I think you're confusing two different forms of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  One says that $\int_C^x{f'(t)\,dt}=f(x)-f(C)$; the other says that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_C^x{f(t)\,dt}=f(x)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!